# Parsing dynamic Spring form edit boxes to controller via bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to persist dynamic edit boxes via a Spring bean.

This is the post method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secure/settings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public String complete( @ModelAttribute("settingsBean") SettingsBean settings, ModelMap model) 
{   
    return ControllerUtils.redirect("/secure/settings");
}
```

This is my "Setting" bean class definition:

```
public class SettingBean 
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

This is my "Settings" bean class definition (note that they are different).

```
public class SettingsBean
{
private List<SettingBean> settings;
}
```

And this is the relevant HTML:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${action}" class = "form-horizontal" modelAttribute="settingsBean" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="setting" items="${settingsBean.settings}">
        <tr>
          <td>${setting.name}</td>
          <td><input name="settings[${setting.id}]" value="${setting.value}" path="value" class="form-control" type="text"/></td>
      </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</div>
</form:form>
```

When the SettingsBean is constructed, the `settings` list is null.

Comment: try with change `<input name="settings[${setting.id}]" value="${setting.value}" path="value" class="form-control" type="text"/>`  to   `<input name="settings[${setting.id}]" value="${setting.value}" path="settings[${setting.value}]" class="form-control" type="text"/>`  for further check [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/)

Answer (score 0):

Spring binds indexed properties using the syntax propertyName[index] where index starts from 0. Use JSTL varStatus attribute of the c:forEach to gather the index value in conjuction with form tag.Change your form to

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${action}" class = "form-horizontal" modelAttribute="settingsBean" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="setting" items="${settingsBean.settings}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
          <td>${setting.name}</td>
          <td><form:input path="settings[${status.index}]" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</div>
</form:form>
```